# Kmeans in R : more cluster centers than distinct data points

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

using kmeans in R cause the following problem :

> Error in kmeans(smpl$LOAN_AMOUNT, centers = 10) :
>   more cluster centers than distinct data points.

I provided a sample of The main dataset that contains a factor attribute with summary :

summary(mydata)

```
100 101 102 131 132 200 201 202 250 251 252 253 254 255 305 424 436 502 550 701 702 705 800 950 
 1 989   1   4   4  18 382  31 412  74   7  15   4   1   1   1   1   4  12   1   3   1  25   5
```

for each factor I want to do clustering on its samples, I know when the number of samples in each factor is not big enough, which cause some empty clusters, the program get fails,

This is my question: 
is there anyway to cluster the data that the number of clusters be at most K ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what the data is showing that you've provided. And, if so, provide the structure of the full data, including counts of samples in each category.

Comment: The first row shows the category(ex. 101 is a category) and the second is counts of samples in that category (ex. 989 samples), the data is contains some attributes of  customers with amount of their account and their category, I want to cluster the customers based on their amount in each category.  the actual number of customers is too much more,

Comment: The first parameter for `kmeans`.. are you supposed to pass in the whole data matrix. At the moment it looks like you're just passing in a column vector from `smpl`

Answer (score 0):

K-means only works on continuous variables.

It needs to compute the *mean*, which is not define for factors.

So if it ignores the factors, all vectors are the same.

Comment: Hi, I used factors just to summary of my data, and As I said above, I wanted to do clustering on samples in each factor not on the factors, there is some continues variable that are considered for clustering, anyway thank you for participation on this question,